# Replacing a dimmer with an ELV (electronic low voltage) dimmer

Tags: electrical, wiring, dimmer-switch

I can not figure what wires in my box should go to the yellow load.

All wires except the double red to the black on the current switch are ringing hot (*with current*).

Also the green ground was not connected when I pulled out existing dimmer.

[image: box1]

[image: box2]

[image: new box]

[image: BOX4]

[image: Box5]

Comment: Where do the two white wires at the top of the first photo go to?

Comment: they both just come in from the same hole near the top of the box and are HOT when I put the voltage detector(pen) to them. there is a closer look if you click the box1 link, not sure why it didnt post like the others. But again, not entirely sure why those are there and they are white with a red stripe if that helps.

Comment: Are you sure they didn't simply get painted/mudded to a white color?

Comment: they are slightly more grey but for sure those two wires have a red line all the way up. What would them being grey mean? opposed to the white wires coming from the top and bottom and the white one going straight through that are for sure the same white.

Comment: I just added another photo, the top left wires are the semi-grey with red stripe, the wires from top and bottom look more white. Also my Main Hot is the two red wires coming from the middle and my neutral seems to be the black.

Comment: How many screws are on the existing switch at this location?  Also, can you carefully scrape some of the paint off those "striped" wires? I'm pretty sure they're solid red, just paint-splattered

Comment: There are two screws on the back of the existing dimmer. I scraped the two striped wires a bit and its still that grey/off white color with a red line that is sometimes broken by a few letters or words that are illegible unfortunately.

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the top of the box then please?

Comment: Posted! please let me know if thats the view you were looking for

Comment: That does explain some of it, but not all....